# Registering keyup on Ctrl when used to change tabs in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, wysiwyg

I have create a wysiwyg HTML editor.  When the user holds down keys down Ctrl, it sets a variable `ctrlPressed` to true.  When the key up event is fired with the Ctrl keycode, then `ctrlPressed` is set to false.

However, when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> to change tabs, there is no way for `ctrlPressed` to be set to false again since when they release the control key, it fires the `keyup` event in the new tab, so when the user returns to the original tab with my website on it, my website still thinks Ctrl is pressed.  That means when they try to type an i, it sets the text to italics and when the user presses "s", the content saves until they press and release Ctrl again.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set the `ctrlPressed` variable to false whenever an user leaves the site, you could attach the `blur()` event to the $(window) element like this:

```
$(window).blur(function(){
    ctrlPressed = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set ctrlPressed to false whenever you detect a new tab is loaded?

Comment: I presume you mean when another tab is selected?  But how does one do this. I've been searching for this very thing, but for some reason, all I find is jQuery UI tab switching.

Comment: You need to go into a bit more detail as to what you have. How are the tabs created? What plugins, if any, have you used? Do you have an example code you can show?

Comment: Maybe attaching the `blur` event to the `$(window)`? Something like `$(window).blur(function(){ ctrlPressed = false });`

Comment: Clever, scumah.  Can you turn that into an answer so I can accept it?